# Storing customer info in angular services

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have a question whether it is best practice in angular to store customer info such as shipping and payment information in services or factories so that we can later access it when we need to make a payment?

Comment: it is better to write the application logic inside services or factories rather than inside of controller. but the sensitive data like payment details should be handle in back-end. handling payment details in client side open a huge risk such as exposing data to unauthorized people.

Comment: we can have a payment factory that can make a request to a 3rd party payment such as paypal or stripe and get back a token from them? That should be okay I believe right?

Comment: for 3rd party application it is fine.